# How to get different footers for different pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

How can I have different footers for different pages in Word 2010? If I change a footer in a page, all footers in other pages are changed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that there is an easy way to do this but what you have to do is you need to put breaks in between the pages. (Page Layout tab > Breaks > "Next Page" on the drop down menu). When your new page comes up, bring out the footer on the second page (double clicking on the bottom of the page) and on the Design menu that pops up on top of your menus deselect "Link to Previous" (same thing can be done to the header).

This should enable you to put a different header for each page.

If someone knows an easier way please enlighten us.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you break the document into "Sections" by inserting section breaks, you can then have different footers in each section.

Answer (score 0):

Put things in gutter margin of those pages

Comment: Try giving a little more detail.

Comment: put gutters and then put boxes with content in that ... its simple as it looks... and stop degrading my score :P

Comment: If your posts are downvoted this means they lack explanation or are unclear. You could [edit] them to provide screenshots, a more detailed description of what to do, etc. For example, here it would be very nice if you could just show us how to "put gutters" and how to "put boxes with content", even if might be obvious to you.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine